# R - Conditionally create new column based on NAs in 3 other columns

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset with the columns Estuarine, Freshwater, and Marine.  I want to create the Status column as such based on the number of NAs in the other columns:

```
Brackish Freshwater Marine  Status
1         NA         1       Marine_Estuarine
1         1          1       Marine_Estuarine_Freshwater
NA        NA         1       Marine_Only
NA        1          1       Marine_Freshwater
```

I tried writing this code to conditionally fill the column but I'm getting an error most rows get labeled as Marine_Only even if they have a 1 in Freshwater or Estuarine.   I thought the "&" would restrict Marine_Only to rows with NAs in both Estuarine and Freshwater.

```
library(dplyr)

df<-df %>%
  mutate(Status = case_when(
    is.na(df$brackish & df$freshwater) ~ "Marine_Only",
    !is.na(df$brackish & df$freshwater) ~ "Marine_Estuarine_and_Freshwater",
    !is.na(df$brackish) ~ "Brackish",
    !is.na(df$freshwater) ~ "Freshwater"))
```

Comment: Mixed up the terms brackish and estuarine, edited post to clarify.

Comment: Also, `R` is case-sensitive.  So if your column name is `Brackish`, lower case wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column names are correct.  The `is.na` can be applied in each column separately, and then do the `&` instead of `brackish & freshwater`.  The latter can be TRUE for any values that are > 0 i.e.

```
> 1 & 2
[1] TRUE
> 0 & 2
[1] FALSE
```

Using the logic described above, create the compound logic expression as below

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(Status = case_when(
          is.na(brackish) & is.na(freshwater) ~ "Marine Only",
          !is.na(brackish) & !is.na(freshwater)
                      ~ "Marine_Estuarine_and_Freshwater",
          !is.na(brackish) ~ "Brackish",
          !is.na(freshwater) ~ "Freshwater"))
```